# Python not saving list values?

Tags: python, list

```
row_4 = [0,0,0,0]
row_3 = [0,0,0,0]
row_2 = [0,0,0,0]
row_1 = [0,0,0,0]
def printer():
    print(row_1)
    print(row_2)
    print(row_3)
    print(row_4)
while True:   
    place_counter = int(input('which column')) 
    test = row_4[place_counter]
    if test == 0:
        row_4.insert((place_counter) , 1)
        place_counter -= 1
        row_4.pop(place_counter)
        print(test)
        printer()

    if test !=0:
        print('not allowed')
        print(test)
```

*when you run this code, you are able to write to row_4 index 1, however when it loops again, if you try to write to index 1 again, it should throw up a 'not allowed' however the program ignores this and jus re writes over row_4 index 1! why is that and how can i fix it?*

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here but the main issue is the order in which you assign a value to and check the value of your `test` variable.

Here is an implementation with some error handling that will achieve what you are trying to do:

```
row_4 = [0,0,0,0]
row_3 = [0,0,0,0]
row_2 = [0,0,0,0]
row_1 = [0,0,0,0]

def printer():
    print(row_1)
    print(row_2)
    print(row_3)
    print(row_4)

while True:   

    # get, parse user input:
    column_number = int(input('Enter column number (-1 to exit): ')) 

    # exit on -1:
    if column_number == -1: break

    # ask user to try again if index is out of bounds:
    if column_number <= -2 or column_number >= 4:
        print('Invalid number, please try again.')
        continue

    # check if the given column has already been updated in row_4:
    if row_4[column_number] == 1:
        print('Already updated, please try again.')
        continue

    # if everything else is okay, update row_4 and call printer():
    row_4[column_number] = 1
    printer()
```